# file write function operand errors

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string filePath = "temporaryfile.txt";
    std::ofstream twrite(filePath.data());
    if (twrite.is_open())
    {
        std::string input;
        std::cin >> input;
        twrite << input;
        
    }
    filePath = "datafile.txt";

    std::ifstream dwrite;
    dwrite.open("datafile.txt");
    if (dwrite.is_open())
    {
        std::string dfile[sizeof(dwrite)];
        std::string tfile;
        int i = 0;
        while (std::getline(dwrite, tfile))
        {
            dfile[i] = tfile;
            i++;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(dwrite); i++)
        {
            dwrite << dfile[i] << std::endl;
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

I was making deliver file "twrite" go to file "dwrite". error is in writing file code :
There is no "<<" operator matching these operands. How can I use operand same that?

Comment: I don't know what you think that `sizeof(dwrite)` means, but it definitely doesn't mean what you think.

Answer (score 2):

In this code:

```
std::ifstream dwrite;
```

you are declaring an `ifstream`, which is an *input* file stream, so you can only read from it. Trying to write into it like this:

```
dwrite << dfile[i] << std::endl;
    // ^^  not supported for ifstream
```

is not allowed.

If you want to both read and write from this file stream, then you can declare it like this:

```
std::fstream dwrite;
dwrite >> /* ... */;  // ok
dwrite << /* ... */;  // ok
```